# Read numeric values contained in double quotes from CSV file

Tags: matlab, csv

I have tried in vain using MATLAB to extract data (so that I can plot it) from a table that comes from a CSV-file. The CSV-file is unlike any I have encountered before and can be found here: https://www.bis.org/statistics/full_webstats_credit_gap_dataflow_csv.zip

The problem is that in the CSV-file everything is noted with double quotations, for example; "Private non-financial sector"," ", or "-57.2". Thus when I use the MATLAB functions `readtable` or `textscan` with `table2array` for a section that only contains numbers it outputs them as a vector of cells, ex: 1×5 cell array; `'56.6'    '57'    '57.2'    '57.9'    '58.3'`

And if I then call an individual cell it outputs it as `T{1}='56.6'`, but sees it as `Size 1x4` and `Value '56.6'` in the workspace, i.e. MATLAB does not see it as the number 56.6 but a collection of symbols.

Can somebody please show me how to use this complicated CSV-file in MATLAB, so that I can plot the data found in specific row?

Thanks in advance!

edit: I have tried different formats, such as `%q`, when using `readtable` or `textscan`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways you could do this but if you have already figured out how to extract the subset(s) of the cell array that contains the data you want, you can simply convert this using `str2double`:

```
>> ca = {'56.1' '13' '12.2' '4.7'}

ca =

  1×4 cell array

    '56.1'    '13'    '12.2'    '4.7'

>> str2double(ca)

ans =

   56.1000   13.0000   12.2000    4.7000
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I had even tried str2double before and could not get it to work for some reason but now its fine. For future readers: it worked for me with readtable => table2array (selecting only numbers) => str2double